# How can I convert a base64 pdf to base64 jpg / jpeg?

Tags: javascript, base64

I need to be able to convert a base64 pdf string to a base64 jpg / jpeg. Any idea
? (Javascript)

Any help appreciated.

Comment: ignore the base64, that's the LEAST of your problems. it's the wrapping paper around your real problem - pdf->jpg conversion.

Comment: these files already comes from the database in base64 format, I don't know if it would be good convert it to PDF and then make the conversion to jpg format, then turn into base64 jpg again

Comment: why bother writing (or finding) a pdf reader that accepts b64 input? b64->binary is a pretty simple operation, and you'll have far better luck finding a b64->binary converter, and a pdf->jpg converter, than a converter that can accept b64.